# unable to remove .php from file extension with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04

I have the following in my .htaccess file. Redirecting the www. works perfectly, as does the custom 404 message. The removal of .php from the file extension fails to work. domain.com/file returns the 404 message, with domain.com/file.php working fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php

#
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Also if it helps this is in my 000-default.conf file

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the code in .htaccess file in your project folder.it might be help for you

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: The problem was a Trailing slash in op's rewrite pattern.  This should work +1

Comment: Thank both of you for the quick response, I made your changes and was still experiencing trouble. After looking at the error logs, I did some more research on the error I was getting. MultiViews did not need to be enabled.